# NTLM Authentication SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 -- Running in SharePoint 2019 & SPWFM

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

Within our environment we're running SharePoint 2019, and have recently upgraded to SharePoint Workflow Manager.

I have a third-party API within our network that authenticates via NTLM. All local testing, as well as testing via REST clients indicate that there is nothing wrong with the actual API.

I would like to call the  API from within a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, however each request to the API is failing with a `Unauthorized` message. I am including the `Authorization: *` API header with the `Http Call` action.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get this `Http Call` action to authenticate using NTLM?